# Sobreponer un div a un modal

Tags: html, css, modal, scss

estaba haciendo un programa con typescript y necesito que en cierto momento aparezca un div por encima del modal fade que hay en pantalla. He probado lo que dicen en internet del z-index pero no funciona, además si le pongo un `z-index` a el modal este se queda como en gris y no funciona.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="infoArticulo" aria-labelledby="transactionModal" aria-hidden="true"><p>Ejemplo</p></div>
<div class="alertas">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="error == 1" >
        <table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span><strong>ERROR!</strong> Solo se pueden introducir números en el campo seleccionado.</span>
                </td>
                <td width="2%">
                    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="reiniciarError()">&Cross;</button>            
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.alertas {
z-index: 1002;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
width: 80%;
//margin-top: 40px;
}
.alertas table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Tengo más código en la página pero no lo pondré porque considero que no es relevante (ya que no influye ni en el div ni en el modal). Cualquiera de los dos divs me vale que se muestre por encima del modal. El modal no lo abro desde un botón sino que lo abro desde código typescript (que como funciona no lo pongo porque creo que solo liará más).

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que he encontrado es un poco fea pero al final lo que he hecho ha sido simplemente abrir un modal y que este modal contenga el div. No es lo ideal pero a mi me ha serivido ya que lo que queria era mostrar un mensaje de error.